# Obtener sólo el ID de un proceso

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, proceso

Quiero hacer un script que cambie la prioridad de un proceso con el paso del tiempo (envejecimiento.sh).

El programa al cual aumentar el valor NICE se llamará primos.sh (hace el cálculo de si un numero, en este caso 100000, es primo o no).

El problema es que, para indicar el PID del proceso al cual quiero aumentar la prioridad del proceso (primos.sh), debo añadir un parámetro al ejecutar envejecimiento.sh (así lo plantee).

¿Hay alguna forma de llamar a la variable $$ (la ID del proceso) de otro script para saber el pid de un script distinto y que no sea necesario añadir el parámetro manualmente?

Estos son mis scripts:
primos.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "El nombre de este script es: $0 y el pid es $$"  
echo "Realizando cálculos, espere por favor..."  
pid=$$  
SECONDS=0  
n=100000  
i=1  
c=1  
while [ $i -le $n ]  
do  
    i=$(expr $i + 1)  
    r=$(expr $n % $i)  
    if [ $r -eq 0 ]  
    then  
        c=$(expr $c + 1)  
    fi  
done  
if [ $c -eq 2 ]  
then  
    echo "El numero es primo"  
else  
    echo "El numero no es primo"  
fi  
temps=$SECONDS  
echo "Ha tardat $(($temps / 60)) minuts i $(($temps % 60)) segons en executarse"
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Introduzca la prioridad inicial: " p  
while [ $p -ge -20 ];  
do  
    renice -n $p -p $1  
    echo "La prioridad ha aumentado en 1 y ahora está en el valor $p"  
    p=$(($p - 1))  
    sleep 5  
done  
if [ $p -eq -20 ]; then  
    echo "El proceso tiene prioridad máxima"
```

Comment: ¿algo así como hace `ps aux | grep ...` para así tener el PID?

Comment: Y cómo seleccionar el valor específico del pid?, además de que me salen dos procesos uno el cual es "grep --color=auto ./primos.sh", cómo indicar solo el primero

Comment: `ps -eo pid` te dará solamente el PID

Comment: `ps -C primos.sh -o pid=` ha funcionado para sacar ese valor. Entonces he introducido en el script la variable `pid=$(ps -C primos.sh -o pid=)` y recoge el valor pid del otro proceso. ¡Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza `pgrep`:

```
$  pgrep -f "<patrón del proceso>"
```

Por ejemplo, vamos a crear al vuelo un programa llamado "proceso personal" (sólo será un largo `sleep`):

```
$ bash -c "exec -a 'proceso personal' sleep 999 & "
```

Entonces, ya sabiendo el nombre, podemos utilizar `pgrep`:

```
$ pgrep -f "proceso personal"
2268
```

Y el id del proceso es 2268.

Utilizamos `-f` para que el patrón se empareje con toda la línea que fue corrida y no sólo con su nombre como aparece con un simple `ps`.

`pgrep` también busca por patrones como si fuese `grep -E`, es decir, expresiones regulares extendidas (Para los que sepan: ¿Es una buena traducción?)

Comment: excelente respuesta

Answer (score 3):

Lo que puedes hacer es buscar el proceso con `ps`. En concreto, puedes hacer `ps aux | grep "tu proceso"` y sacar el PID exacto.

En lugar de parsear la salida de `ps`, puedes pedírselo directamente diciendo `ps -eo pid` y así te dará exactamente el PID, nada más.